# Image generation with Emoji issue on Java

Tags: java, utf-8, emoji

Currently, when I try to print/log/generate image with code on
https://emojiterra.com/pilot/
for noto image:
\uD83E\uDDD1\u200D\u2708\uFE0F.
It always show 2 emoji: ‍✈️ instead of 1 emoji for noto. [image]

log.info("\uD83E\uDDD1\u200D\u2708\uFE0F") always display ‍✈️

When using Graphics2D, it generate image like this:
[image]
I guess the issue happen is because java only support 16-bit characters, and noto emoji is a 32-bit.

Is there a way that I can print/generate image with 32-bit emoji in java?

Comment: Interestingly, your question shows a single pilot emoji in my browser.  I’m guessing you meant to say that the log shows ✈️.  This suggests that your string is correct;  the problem lies with how you are viewing the log.  Not all editors and text viewers are aware of the full set of Unicode emoji sequences.

Comment: not only the logs, but when I tried to generate image using Graphics2D, the image also contains 2 emojj instead of 1 noto image.

Comment: I’m nearly certain that the Java 2D renderer recognizes few, if any, Unicode emoji sequences.  Though I’m not sure to what extent such rendering is the font’s responsibility.

Comment: Java can handle supplementary characters since Java 5. Your emoji, however, consists of two codepoints combined with a zero-width-joiner, followed by a variant selector. Software only understanding 16 bit characters would say that this string has five chars (as `string.length()` would do), but `string.codePointCount(0, string.length())` will correctly tell you that there are four codepoints. Whereas `new Scanner("\uD83E\uDDD1\u200D\u2708\uFE0F") .findAll("\\X").count()` will tell you whether it is recognized as one logical character (it is with Java 13 and newer). The font also matters, though

Comment: The problem is my project using java 8 now. Do I need to upgrade java to 13 or higher to make it work?